# Sharepoint Refinement Panel showing GUID

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

I am having the same problem as this post: [social.msdn.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv-LV/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/b8697442-bd82-4746-9df6-7782d5c12ba6).
I am aware that they have an answer but I can't seem to understand what they mean.

So I have set up a managed property and then added it to my refinement panel using this code:

```
<Category    Title="Loan Category"    Description="Use this filter to restrict results by Loan Category"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="LoanCategory"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer"  />
```

However when I do a search it displays all kinds of GUIDs for the categories as well as the categories I am looking for. I am pretty sure this did not happen when I just had this set up in test.

The crawled properties that I have mapped to this managed property are as follows:
Loan Category(Text), ows_Loan_x0020_Category(Text), Loan_x0020_Category(Text)

I originally had "ows_taxId_Loan_x0020_Category(Text)" mapped as well however I removed it after reading this might be the issue. Ran a full crawl and still no luck. I have also reset the search index and run a full crawl.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link that is being generated by the refinement panel:

```
<a title="Refine By: #96dbf06d-8bf8-4ec5-971b-36e27fba1f62;Loan Sale:Participation and Servicing Agreement;#4ac5410c-79e9-4a9a-99fb-66592342ed16;#51e388cd-62df-4e50-98b4-01af5f776aea;#04ac5410c-79e9-4a9a-99fb-66592342ed16" class="ms-searchref-filterlink" id="ext-gen151" href="/Search/Pages/results.aspx?k=LoanCategory%3AServicing&r=loancategory%3D%22%2396dbf06d%2D8bf8%2D4ec5%2D971b%2D36e27fba1f62%3BLoan%20Sale%3AParticipation%20and%20Servicing%20Agreement%3B%234ac5410c%2D79e9%2D4a9a%2D99fb%2D66592342ed16%3B%2351e388cd%2D62df%2D4e50%2D98b4%2D01af5f776aea%3B%2304ac5410c%2D79e9%2D4a9a%2D99fb%2D66592342ed16%22">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the GUIDs were showing in my refinement panel because they were in fact the contents of one of the crawled properties that was mapped to my managed property.

In order to determine which one I created a managed property for each of the crawled properties and added them individually. I then did an search index reset from central administration and re-ran a full crawl.

I found the guid in the database which gave me the heads up. In the database go to your search db and look for the table MSSManagedProperties. **Your db name may be different.**

```
Select * from [_SearchDB].[dbo].[MSSManagedProperties]
```

Get the managed property you want and then do a query on PropertyStore database table MSSDocProps based on the Pid.

```
Select strVal2 FROM [_SearchDB_PropertyStore].[dbo].[MSSDocProps]  where Pid = ?
```

This gives you an idea of what data you are getting for that managed property.